# How to disable the future date in the jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, datepicker

I tried to disable the future date in date picker but thing is it has been disable the month and the year.

following is the code.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Week Calculation</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="JavaScript/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="JavaScript/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="daterange">
        <p>Date1: <input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="date1"></p>
        <p>Date2: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="date2"></p>
      <p> <label> Enter search Text: </label> <input type="text" id="byrange" name="searchText"> </p>
        <p> <input type="submit" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: see this id different question. even i posted with screenshot also. i want disable the future date but user can able to select the month and year drop down for some thing like previous year or previous month selection.

Comment: reopened the question now.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ maxDate: new Date);
```

or

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({  maxDate: '0'});
```

Comment: Would it be useful, because moth and year dropdown are allowed to select future dates.

Comment: please explain how you select future date in http://jsfiddle.net/catch_shailendra/VBGKU/687/

Comment: But, what if OP want to allow selection of future year dates and disable specific dates in current year or month.

Comment: than you should ask how to disable "specific dates"  not future date look at the question first

Comment: Ok, you haven't read it carefully. OP doesn't want to disable month and year dropdown.

Comment: in my fiddle drop-downs are not disable, they just not allowed future date as question said

Comment: Sure, but it is not allowing to select future dates.

Comment: see this id different question. even i posted with screenshot also. i want disable the future date but user can able to select the month and year drop down for some thing like previous year or previous month selection.